# Voice Chat over WiFi iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, video, sdk, chat, voice

how I can implement a voice (and maybe a video) chat over the Wifi Network ? Internet connection will not be required. Tried the GK Stuff, but this only works over bluetooth, right ?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Depends on some things: Do you want to use a VoIP Protocol? Do you want to integrate this chat in your application? How much effort can go into this implementation? I mean, the encoding and decoding involved in a voice chat is not trivial.

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer... It will be not a app for the store, I can implement all what I want (maybe a license who I can sell). But now I've read, that I can use the GameKit Stuff in a WiFi Network as well ?